# PassportJS Executing the wrong Database Query

Tags: mysql, passport.js, sequelize.js, passport-local

I am running into an issue where my PassportJS code is issuing the exact same query (using sequelize) every time I login regardless of the username and password being inputted and as a result I am successfully logged in each time. I feel like the issue is within my localStrategy code, but I can't seem to tell.

For Instance: I am logging in with user_id=3, email=test3@gmail.com, password=test

and this is the resulting sql output:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `user_id`, `first_name` AS `firstName`, `last_name` AS `lastName`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `user` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`user_id` = 1;
```

It shouldn't be querying `user_id=1` and was never checking the values in the input because the successful redirect for the login route is being triggered.

Here is my passport configuration and routing:

```
  var express = require('express');
    var siteRoutes  = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var models = require('../models/db-index');

    /*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/

    // Serialize sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log(user.user_id + "Serializing");
      done(null, user.user_id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
      models.User.find({where: {user_id: user_id}}).then(function(user){
        done(null, user);
      }).error(function(err){
        done(err, null);
      });
    });


    passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true,
        usernameField: 'email'
        }, 
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            console.log(req.body.email);
            console.log(req.body.password);
            //Find user by email
            models.User.findOne({ 
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password
            }).then(function(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Email not found.'));
            });
        }
        ));

/*====  Login   ====*/


siteRoutes.route('/login')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/login.hbs');
    })

    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/sign-up',
        failureFlash: true
    }));



siteRoutes.route('/sign-up')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/sign-up.hbs');
    })

    .post(function(req, res){

        models.User.create({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        }).then(function() { 
        res.redirect('/');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
    })

});








module.exports = siteRoutes;
```

User Model:

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
    return User;
}
```

the `model` variable is just a connector file for my various models. Please let me know if seeing that code would help

Comment: Some questions to try and narrow in on this: When is the query below being executed? What is the output of your console.log calls in the passport local login strategy? What is the output if you log the user that is found in your passport local login strategy by the findOne before calling passport's done function? 

SELECT `user_id`, `first_name` AS `firstName`, `last_name` AS `lastName`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `user` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`user_id` = 1;

Comment: @cfogelberg thanks for the advice. I added different console logs and was able to see that the execution of the SQL code was at the `findOne` method. It also appeared to me that there wasn't a `Where` clause in the SQL which indicated to me that the query was never looking for the field values. I changed the `findOne` method to include the `where` clause and it fixed my issues

Comment: Good spot on the missing where: clause in the findOne